# How do I connect a Raspberry Pi to my PC using HDMI?

Tags: pi-3, hdmi

I have inserted my SD card with the OS and all that but when I insert the HDMI into my PC it does not seem to load up, how can I make it boot with my PC?
Do I need an Ethernet cable or something like that?

Comment: The HDMI port on your computer is an output not an input. If you only want commandline you can use SSH if you want a graphical desktop use VNC

Answer (score 2):

I've tried tethering my HDMI cable to my MacBook but then discovered that a standard MacBook Pro does not have a video-input- so I resolved by connecting my LCD TV to my Raspberry Pi via HDMI.

You could also create a [VPN with VNC connect](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/)- fairly simple.

If you discover a solution to connect your MacBook to your Raspberry Pi, please comment- because I would also like to know.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you have an external display (i.e. a TV with an HDMI port or a desktop monitor) you can simply use that to get started. However, if you don't have that, you can follow [this guide](https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/) which should get you started.
The linked page walks you through using a laptop screen as a display for your Pi. Luckily, all you need is an Ethernet cable!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest answer is connect your Pi HDMI output to the HDMI port on a standard display or TV. The HDMI port on Apple computers is output ONLY.